# How to get a BarContainer Object from an AxesSubplot object in matplotllib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I'm fairly new with matplotlib, but as I understand:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplot()
ax.bar(x,y)
```

## or

```
bar = ax.bar(x,y)
```

returns a BarContainer type object. From this we can `bar.axes` to get the axes ax on which this is plotted.

but what if we have an axes `ax` and we didn't explicitly store the barplot in a `bar` object. 
Now we go ahead and do a whole lot of changes on the axes `ax`, as in `ax.position ax.legend` etc etc.
Now we have an `AxesSubplot` type object `ax`....from this, how can we extract our `BarContainer` type object?

I have a function that accepts the subscriptable `BarContainer` object, and by the end of my processing I only have an `AxesSubplot` type object... I can't figure out how to get one from the other..
We can get artists, labels, axis etc etc from the `AxesSubplot` object but I see no way to get the `Container` type object from it. Please assist, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of all containers in the axes by using `ax.containers`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y) 

con = ax.containers
print(con)
# [<BarContainer object of 3 artists>]
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what i was looking for, couldn't find it anywhere in the docs.

Comment: @Kriticoder I also can't find it anywhere in the docs. But if you do `print(dir(ax))` it tells you a list of attributes for the axes object. Which is how I found the `.containers`!

Comment: I used `[f'ax.{fn}' for fn in dir(ax) if 'contain' in fn.lower()]` which is similar

Answer (score 0):

Also you can label each bar in your bar plot using this code below. The size part is optional:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], size=20)
```