# How to get data from matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

How does one retrieve data programmatically from a matplotlib bar chart? I can do it for a matplotlib line chart as follows, so maybe I'm fairly close:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])

axis = plt.gca()
line = axis.lines[0]
x_plot, y_plot = line.get_xydata().T
print("x_plot: ", x_plot)
print("y_plot: ", y_plot)
```

for a bar chart, however, there are no lines, and I'm unclear what the equivalent object is:

```
plt.bar([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
axis = plt.gca()
???
```

FWIW, here are a couple of related postings (that don't go into bar charts):

- [How to extract data from matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938449/how-to-extract-data-from-matplotlib-plot#8939010)
- [Retrieve XY data from matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130768/retrieve-xy-data-from-matplotlib-figure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The API for [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) returns a [`BarContainer`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/container_api.html#matplotlib.container.BarContainer) object

  - [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib-patches-rectangle) provides a full accounting of the `Patch` methods.
  - This object is iterable, and the various location components can be extracted with the appropriate methods, as shown below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rects = plt.bar([1,2,3], [4,5,6])

for rect in rects:
    print(rect)
    xy = rect.get_xy()
    x = rect.get_x()
    y = rect.get_y()
    height = rect.get_height()
    width = rect.get_width()

[out]:
Rectangle(xy=(0.6, 0), width=0.8, height=4, angle=0)
Rectangle(xy=(1.6, 0), width=0.8, height=5, angle=0)
Rectangle(xy=(2.6, 0), width=0.8, height=6, angle=0)
```

[image]

Comment: As a followup, is there way to get the BarContainer from the plot object, not the return of calling "bar"?

Comment: nevermind, found the answer:

ax = plot.gca()
con = ax.containers
print(con)

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62189677/how-to-get-a-barcontainer-object-from-an-axessubplot-object-in-matplotllib